# Sorting alphanumerically in Excel

Tags: excel

I've changed the column to text a couple of different ways, but still cannot get the numbers with alpha to sort correctly.  The three all number and four alpha numeric entries are sorting correctly.  Anyone have a solution they can offer up?  Thanks!

[image: Incorrect alphanumberic sort]

Comment: Please update this question with a specific example of your data and your desired result.

Comment: That is because of the way Excel sorts text, letter by letter.  You will need to make all the numbers the same number of digits. If the max number of digits is 2: `69D` then all other numbers must have two digits: `05D`,`06` and so on.  Or separate the numbers from the text and sort on two columns.